# How to compute the standard error of the variable $- \frac{\hat{\beta}_0}{\hat{\beta}_1}$ of a logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, standard-error

I've got the following data with a logistic regression model

```r
# data
   score_dicho score
   <lgl>       <dbl>
 1 FALSE         175
 2 FALSE         175
 3 FALSE         175
 4 FALSE         175
 5 FALSE         189
 6 FALSE         189
 7 FALSE         189
 8 FALSE         189
 9 FALSE         210
10 FALSE         210

data <- structure(list(score_dicho = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), score = c(175, 175, 175, 175, 189, 189, 189, 189, 210, 210, 210, 210, 221, 221, 221, 221, 235, 235, 235, 235, 247, 247, 247, 247, 275, 275, 275, 275, 278, 278, 278, 278, 288, 288, 288, 288, 317, 317, 317, 317, 329, 329, 329, 329, 348, 348, 348, 348, 362, 362, 362, 362, 375, 375, 375, 375, 387, 387, 387, 387, 403, 403, 403, 403, 412, 412, 412, 412, 431, 431, 431, 431, 445, 445, 445, 445, 451, 451, 451, 451, 462, 462, 462, 462, 472, 472, 472, 472, 485, 485, 485, 485, 497, 497, 497, 497, 503, 503, 503, 503, 512, 512, 512, 512, 525, 525, 525, 525, 535, 535, 535, 535, 547, 547, 547, 547, 556, 556, 556, 556, 578, 578, 578, 578, 593, 593, 593, 593, 601, 601, 601, 601, 614, 614, 614, 614, 628, 628, 628, 628, 650, 650, 650, 650)), row.names = c(NA, -144L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mod_log <- glm(score_dicho ~ score, data = data, family = "binomial")

summary(mod_log)
# Call:
# glm(formula = score_dicho ~ score, family = "binomial", data = data)
# 
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -16.354969   4.024865  -4.063 4.83e-05 ***
# score         0.026506   0.006896   3.844 0.000121 ***
```

How to compute the standard error of the estimates of the variable $$ - coef(Intercept)/coef(score)$$ ?

Or the confidence intervals.

NB : I'd like another method than the bootstrap.

Comment: Unlike linear regression, there's not a bunch of known analytical results for the parameters in logistic regression, so it's much harder to compute the standard error. The most obvious is indeed to use bootstrapping, which you said you did not want to do. I think your next best option is to try to calculate the joint posterior for your two regression coefficients, which will involve a pretty arduous calculation of the evidence term. This will then give you a bivariate distribution you can sample from and you can simply take many samples, calculate the ratio and average over the samples.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without computing analytically the distribution?

Comment: If I have to compute the joint distribution, how to do so ?

Comment: The variable $\hat\beta_0/\hat\beta_1$ follows a ratio distribution with an infinite mean. So computing a standard error is not so trivial. You could however compute the standard error for the limiting/approximate distribution that follows a normal distribution (in a similar way as here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438402/)

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) (see also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192171/test-statistic-for-a-ratio-of-regression-coefficients)). Another is simulation-based inference as described in the paper by [King et al. (2000)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2669316) with a recent exploration of simulation-based inference by [Rainey (2023)](https://doi.org/10.1017/psrm.2023.8). There is also the bootstrap, although you mention that you don't want to use it.

But note that the ratio estimator will be [biased](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390180/ratio-of-unbiased-estimators).

**Delta method**

The [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) package for `R` makes applying the delta method very easy. For your example:

```
library(car)

deltaMethod(mod_log, "-b0/b1", parameterNames = paste0("b", 0:1))
       Estimate      SE   2.5 % 97.5 %
-b0/b1  617.024  16.157 585.358 648.69
```

The point estimate is $617.02$ with an approximate 95% confidence interval of $(585.36;\;648.69)$.

**Simulation-based inference (CLARIFY)**

The simulation-based inference involves the following steps:

1. Estimate the model and store the coefficients and variance-covariance matrix.
2. Draw $n$ coefficient vectors from a multivariate normal distribution with the mean and covariance matrix equal to the estimated ones in step 1.
3. Calculate the quantity of interest for each of the $n$ draws.
4. Calculate the point estimate and 95% confidence intervals based on the $n$ calculated quantities of interest by taking the average and $0.025/0.975$ quantiles, respectively.

The [`clarify`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=clarify) package for `R` makes this easy. Again for your data and model:

```
# Reproducibility
set.seed(142857)

# Simulate 100000 coefficients from the model
s <- sim(mod_log, n = 1e5)

# Define the function that calculates the negative ratio of the coefficients
my_fun <- function(fit) {
  betas <- unname(coef(fit))
  c("-b0/b1" = -betas[1]/betas[2])
}

# Apply the function to the simulated coefficients earlier
est1 <- sim_apply(s, FUN = my_fun)

# Plot and summaries the results
plot(est1) # Not shown
print(summary(est1), digits = 5)
       Estimate  2.5 % 97.5 %
-b0/b1   617.02 590.77 667.40

confint(est1)
          2.5 %   97.5 %
-b0/b1 590.7698 667.3992
```

The simulation-based estimate is $617.02$ with a 95% confidence interval of $(590.77;\; 667.40)$.

**Nonparametric bootstrap**

To complete the answer, here is an analysis using the (nonparametric, case-resampling) bootstrap, also implemented in the `car` package:

```
library(car)
set.seed(142857) # Reproducibility
# Bootstrap
res_boot <- Boot(mod_log, f = function(obj){-coef(obj)[1]/coef(obj)[2]}, R = 999)
summary(res_boot)
             R original bootBias bootSE bootMed
(Intercept) 999   617.02   1.3104 18.998  616.14

confint(res_boot)
Bootstrap bca confidence intervals

               2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept) 588.2415 664.4407
```

The bootstrap standard error is $18.998$ with a 95% confidence interval of $(588.24;\;664.44)$. This is very close to the simulation-based confidence intervals.

**References**

King, G., Tomz, M., & Wittenberg, J. (2000). Making the most of statistical analyses: Improving interpretation and presentation. American journal of political science, 347-361.

Rainey, C. (2023). A careful consideration of CLARIFY: simulation-induced bias in point estimates of quantities of interest. Political Science Research and Methods, 1-10.

Comment: @Julien I've used the `car` package because it's so easy. I also know of the `msm` package that also implements the delta method. But it's also fairly easy to code it "by hand" for this case.

Comment: With `car` I get a bigger standard error than with a stratified bootstrap, is this expected ?

Comment: @Julien It's possible because the delta method relies on a normal approximation whereas the bootstrap uses the empirical sampling distribution which can be far from normal. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146704/discussion-between-julien-and-coolserdash).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus You're probably right since the `glm` function shows a warning : `Warning message: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`

Comment: @Julien When I use your data from the question, I don't get this error.

Comment: Great answer, and thank you for illustrating a nice use of `clarify` :)

Answer (score 5):

Aside from

1. simulations
2. bootstrapping
3. delta method

another way is to

4. re-parameterize the model

In your case this can be done by modeling the Bernoulli distribution probability parameter $p$ as

$$p = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_1x)}} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_1 (x+\beta_0/\beta_1)}} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_1 (x-\beta_2)}}$$

where the parameter $\beta_2 = \beta_0/\beta_1$ on the right-hand side is what you are looking for.

This parameter value and it's standard error can be estimated by using any optimization algorithm. The Hessian of the log likelihood can be used to estimate the covariance and the standard error.

Example code:

```
set.seed(1)
y = data$score_dicho
x = data$score

###
### approach using car package deltaMethod
###

mod_log <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial())
mod_log
car::deltaMethod(mod_log, "-b0/b1", parameterNames = c("b0","b1"))
### solution : 617.024
### se       :  16.157

###
### approach using manual fit with optim
###
logL2 = function(par) {
  ab = par[1]
  b = par[2]
  p = 1/(1+exp(-b*(x-ab)))
  -sum(dbinom(y,1,p, log = TRUE))
}

# optim function to get the fit
opt = optim(c(600,0.02),logL2, hessian = TRUE, control = list(parscale = c(600,0.03), ndeps = c(10^-6,10^-6)))
opt
sqrt(solve(opt$hessian)[1,1])   ### <--- this thing here is the SE estimate

### solution : 617.027
### se       :  16.16775
```

Comment: +1. It's interesting that your standard error is virtually identical to that from the delta method.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I believe that, being based on the gradient, a first order approximation, it should be exactly identical and the discrepancies are only in the computation. (Here is a case where there *is* a difference https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/481446/ but that is the case when the entire variable is transformed and not just the model for the parameters of the distribution)

Comment: What is $p$ in the equation ? Is it the proportion of `TRUE` in the response variable (`score_dicho` here)?

Comment: @Julien I used $p$ as the parameter of the assumed Bernoulli distribution $$P(Y=y|p) = \begin{cases}p &\qquad \text{if y = 1} \\ 1-p &\qquad \text{if y = 0} \\ 0 &\qquad \text{else} \end{cases}$$ for the binary observations $Y$ (which in your code are, I believe `data$score_dicho`)

Comment: You mean $P(Y=y|x) = \begin{cases}p &\qquad \text{if y = 1} \\ 1-p &\qquad \text{if y = 0} \\ 0 &\qquad \text{else} \end{cases}$ ?

Comment: $p$ is eventually a function of $x$ then it would be $$P(Y=y|x) = \begin{cases} p(x) &\qquad \text{if y = 1} \\ 1-p(x) &\qquad \text{if y = 0} \\ 0 &\qquad \text{else} \end{cases}$$ where $$p(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(a+bx)}}$$ so with $p$ I mean the conditional probability, and $p$ is considered a (logistic) function of the features/regressors $x$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon my comment/answer your question:

When you do standard out-of-the-box logistic regression, you are calculating the maximum likelihood estimators $\hat{\beta}_{0}, \hat{\beta}_{1}$

which are given by

$$argmin_{\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}} \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}\ln\sigma(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1}) + (1-y_{i})\ln (1 - \sigma(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1}))$$

where I'm using $\sigma(x)$ to denote $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

For what's to come, it will be instructive to note that this is equivalent to writing:

$$argmin_{\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}} \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}\ln p(y_{i}|x_{i}, \beta_{0}, \beta_{1})=argmin_{\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}} \ln P(Data|\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})$$

If instead of having a maximum-likelihood estimator but wanted to come up with a posterior distribution for $(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})$, you would do this using Bayes' rule

$$p(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}| D)  = \frac{p(D|\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})p(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})}{\int p(D|\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})p(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})d\beta_{0}\beta_{1}}$$

You already have an expression for the likelihood term, albeit it's a bit more complicated if you don't take the log, it's given by

$$\prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma(\beta_{0}+ \beta_{1}x_{i})^{y_{i}}(1 - \sigma( \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}))^{1-y_{i}}$$

and you will have to choose some suitable prior $p(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})$ that corresponds to your intuition.

So in theory, I've written down an analytic expression for your posterior function, but this isn't entirely trivial to evaluate (which is why Bayesian inference and MCMC are a discipline unto themselves). The denominator is not something you can calculate analytically, you'll have to solve it numerically.

Note however that you don't technically need to know the posterior, you just need to be able to sample from it, as what you care about is getting a posterior for the quantity $\frac{\beta_{0}}{\beta_{1}}$. Because $(\beta_{0},\beta_{1})$ will be correlated, even if you had access to the joint posterior it would be non-trivial to calculate the distribution of their ratio. A more pragmatic way to proceed would be to sample $(\beta_{0},\beta_{1})$ pairs from the distribution, calculate the ratios every time and take an average and std over many such ratios.

This only requires you to be able to sample from the posterior, and there is a whole literature on how to sample from un-normalised distributions. In this case, that means treating your posterior as

$$ p(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}) = \alpha \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{N}\sigma(\beta_{0}+ \beta_{1}x_{i})^{y_{i}}(1 - \sigma( \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}))^{1-y_{i}}$$

In conclusion, you can see why people tend to solve this problem by bootstrapping

Comment: Once you have the distribution, do you use the inverse CDF technique to produce samples?

Comment: no, because it's a 2 dimensional pdf. If you have the full distribution, you can use a sampling technique that works well in low dimensions like Metropolis-Hastings or Gibbs sampling. 

But as I said, it's hard to calculate the full pdf as you have to evaluate that integral, it's much easier to get the un-normalised pdf (or even easier to get the log thereof), and there are tweaks one can make to the aforementioned sampling techniques that allow you to sample from unnormalised distributions

Comment: Is the first part $\hat{\beta}_0,\hat{\beta}_0$ an error? I'm not sure if I understood that part.

Comment: yes, thanks, should beta $\hat{\beta}_{0}, \hat{\beta}_{1}$, will edit